# Arrow date in a pandas column

Tags: date, type-conversion, arrow-functions

I am using arrow to get the dates of a single dataframe that has the following structure:

```
data=['2015', '2016','2017', '2108']
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['time'])
```

I know that to get the date in arrow is with the following code:

```
arrow.get('2016')
```

Have tried to use this:

```
arrow.get(df['time'])
```

But it gives me this error:  Cannot parse single argument of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.

How to tell arrow to use the column?

Thanks

Comment: What data and type are you trying to get?  All the dates?  One single date?  pd.apply might be your friend for reformatting the whole column.  Or maybe using converters in read_csv if you happen to be reading in from a file in your actual use case.

Comment: Datetime from the column.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert the entire series for access later**

One option is to use pandas `apply` on the column.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

`df.time = df.time.apply(lambda tm: arrow.get(tm))`

Might be a way to do this with converters on load as well, depending on where you are loading from.  csv docs for example, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

I also wonder why you are using arrow time versus pandas built in datetime type.  Once again, depending on how you are loading this data, dtypes could be used to specify datetime.

**Convert one value from the series**

You need to choose one value instead of providing all values (i.e. the pd.Series)

`arrow.get(df.time[1])` would convert 2016 in your example.